# Filter numbers from an array which share the same digit without knowing the digit beforehand

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for an easy way to do the following:
I have an array of random numbers between 0-99. I need two arrays, first which have values which share the same first digit, second for values that share the same second digit. It doesn't matter what that digit is, as long as it occurs more than once. 0-9 is to be treated as if the first digit was 0.

To illustrate the problem:
`[0, 10, 20, 11, 19, 12, 54, 64, 23, 24]` would result in `[10, 11, 12, 19, 23, 24]` and `[0, 10, 20, 24, 54, 64]`. Some values can go in both arrays if they meet the criteria.

I've found solutions that are useful if you know the digit you're comparing. However, not in this scenario.

I know the way to begin is to convert numbers inside the array into strings: `array.map(String)`, so that the second and first digit can be accessed by `first[0]`, `second[1]`. I don't know how to proceed from there, though. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why value 10 is not in second array? Why 19 is in the second array?

Comment: @Hassan Honest mistake, sorry. I've switched the order of the arrays so the first one represents the first digit pairs, second one for second digit pairs. 19 is there because it shares '1' as the first digit with 10, 11, 12

Comment: But 19 is not there in the original array.

Comment: Whoopsie, another honest mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your array based on first digit and last digit in an object accumulator. Then, filter the grouped array based on length.

```js
const input = [0, 10, 20, 11, 19, 12, 54, 64, 23, 24],
      groupLastDigits = input.reduce((r, n) => {
        const last = n % 10;
        r[last] ??= [];
        r[last].push(n);
        return r;
      }, {}),
      groupFirstDigits = input.reduce((r, n) => {
        let first = Math.floor(n / 10);
        if(first === n) first = 0;
        r[first] ??= [];
        r[first].push(n);
        return r;
      }, {}),
      getNumbers = o => Object.values(o).filter(arr => arr.length > 1).flat()
      commonLastDigits = getNumbers(groupLastDigits),
      commonFirstDigits = getNumbers(groupFirstDigits);
console.log(commonLastDigits);
console.log(commonFirstDigits);
```

Comment: Looks great and works great, thank you. What does '??=' do in this scenario?

Comment: This is the Logical Nullish Assignment operator. This operator will update a variable with a new value, but only if that variable currently holds a "nullish" value (either null or undefined).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a generic solution for `n` digits!

```js
let matchingDigitGroups = function*(arr) {
  
  // Note that very large numbers will convert to string
  // in scientific notation, breaking this approach
  let maxDigits = Math.max(...arr.map(num => `${num}`.length));
  let strs = arr.map(num => {
    let str = `${num}`;
    while (str.length < maxDigits) str = `0${str}`;
    return str;
  });
  
  for (let i = 0; i < maxDigits; i++) {
    
    let result = [];
    for (let n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
      let matchDigits = strs.filter(str => str[i] === `${n}`);
      if (matchDigits.length > 1) result.push(...matchDigits);
    }
    yield result;
    
  }
  
};

let tests = [
  [ 0, 10, 20, 11, 19, 12, 54, 64, 23, 24 ],
  [ 100, 200, 300 ],
  [ 111, 222, 333, 771, 828, 399 ],
  [],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 92929, 91919 ]
];
for (let arr of tests) {
  console.log(`Groups for: [ ${arr.join(', ')} ]`);
  for (let group of matchingDigitGroups(arr)) console.log(`  [ ${group.join(', ')} ]`);
}
```